# How does my question about Ubuntu 18.04 DNS name resolution fail to meet SO guidelines?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

I posted the question [Ubuntu 18.04 DNS name resolution fails after connecting USB CAN-FD interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439324/ubuntu-18-04-dns-name-resolution-fails-after-connecting-usb-can-fd-interface) a few days ago. SO closed it with no explanation beyond this:

> Closed. This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers.

> We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow. You can edit the question so it’s on-topic for Stack Overflow or post a new one on Super User.

The question is obviously about a specific failure involving a specific device on a specific version of a specific OS.
SO offers no recourse, no appeal, and no way even to ask what the offense was. I can't even title this question "What makes this question off-topic?"

Apparently, our robotic overlords don't like to have their decisions questioned.

Hopefully someone here can enlighten me as to how this question fails to meet SO guidelines.

Comment: The users of Stackoverflow closed your question. Stackoverflow is intended for programming and software development questions. Reread this part of the explanation: `We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for replying, but simply repeating what has already been said adds nothing to the discussion. I can find dozens of questions on SO regarding DNS name resolution failures - what makes this question different?

Comment: I understand your dilemma. Your question was closed by regular users like you and me (I did not close your question) by voting to close your question (3 votes will close your question) and not some robot. The fact that your question is off-topic and was closed AND other questions are off-topic and were not closed is an interesting factor that personally I disagree with. However, your question was closed. Create a new question on a forum that supports your type of question. https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: I voted to close your first question and now this one.Because it is still offtopic on this website, no matter how many other offtopics questions there are.Don't take it personally, moderation is a human activity, it is not perfect, and rules also change over time.SO having been the first site before the explosion of other StackExchange websites means a lot of people consider this one to be an "all stop" for any question... but it isn't. Also when you say "SO offers no recourse, no appeal, and no way even to ask what the offense was." It is simple not true, read the message in the close text.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - Thanks, I read it before I copied it into this post. Perhaps you can point out to me where it states the course of appeal, and the means of obtaining clarification of how my post deviated from the rules.

Comment: Course of appeal: "You can edit the question so it’s on-topic for Stack Overflow or post a new one on Super User.". How post deviated from the rules: "We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow.". You can always refer back to the help section, and specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - You're confusing remediation with appeal. And saying (over and over again) that SO doesn't allow a nebulously defined category of question does not tell me how my post fits into that category. What is "general" about my question? Can you help me understand what a less "general" question would be?

Comment: @Scioomnemalumhoc "General" here means "any computing problem that is not _also_ a **programming** problem".

Comment: _"You're confusing remediation with appeal"_ What _exactly_ are you trying to appeal? Do you believe that the problem presented in your question is a programming problem? If so, edit the post and make that very clear. Do you agree that it's not a programming problem but you think we should change the rules to make it on-topic? If so, post a question here on meta requesting that. Hint: Before doing so, make sure to do your research to make sure your request is not a duplicate and be prepared that the community _might_ disagree with your request and express that using votes.

Comment: @41686d6564 - Thanks - my misunderstanding of that only became clear after PatrickMevzek's final comment. Up to that point, the reason my question was not allowed was only expressed as a prohibition against "general" questions, along with the always popular RTFM.

Comment: @41686d6564 - I didn't notice that PatrickMevzek had deleted his final comment before this question was migrated - sorry if that was confusing. It was the first time he had mentioned that SO was now only about programming.

Comment: @41686d6564 - The notion of appeal seems to be causing some confusion as well. An appeal is the review of a decision. The opportunity to correct a problem - recognized or otherwise - is not an appeal, by definition.
An appeal is appropriate when you don't agree with a decision. If you don't understand the rationale for a decision, you will be unable to agree with it. Information was what I was lacking, and information was what I was asking for. 
Ultimately, the light bulb did come on.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is obviously about a specific failure involving a specific device on a specific version of a specific OS.

Your question is about Domain Name Server / Name resolution for a specific piece of hardware once you plug it into a machine. That is not a programming problem as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which states a question needs to be about:

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

> SO offers no recourse, no appeal, and no way even to ask what the offense was.

We do offer that. Once you read the guidance offered in the links of the post notice, you can rectify what was missing or went South in your question. If you still have doubts you can ask on [Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Once you made a substantial rectifying edit your post will go into the re-open queue where users with re-open privileges will assess your question again. Alternatively users that follow their tags will see your question pop-up on their Active tab.

> Apparently, our robotic overlords don't like to have their decisions questioned.

Apparently, our robotic askers don't like to familiarize themselves with guidance offered in the help center or [in the right side-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U8Lt.png)

> Hopefully someone here can enlighten me as to how this question fails to meet SO guidelines

See the comments on your question. I also point out the guidance offered in the tag wiki's for the tag [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dns/info) and [ubuntu-18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ubuntu-18.04/info) which happened to be the tags you used on your question.

From your comments I address this one:

> I can find dozens of questions on SO regarding DNS name resolution failures

Yes, we didn't process those yet to close them all. We'll get to them eventually.
Do note that finding a question that is similar to yours doesn't make a question on-topic. So if you have a problem with your Apple, don't post on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) because they also have questions about apples.